# Wordpress - Facebook og error

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I can't really figured out where i am doing wrong, about my link share on Facebook.

Example content : http://www.cppturkce.com/rand-ile-zar-ornegi/
And this is my og:tags

```
<!-- Facebook Open Graph Tags added by WP Facebook Like Send & Open Graph Meta v1.3.2: http://tutskid.com/facebook-like-send-opengraph-wp-plugin/ --><meta property='og:locale' content='tr_TR'/>
<meta property="og:title" content="rand ile zar atma örneği" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.cppturkce.com/rand-ile-zar-ornegi/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cppturkce.com/fb.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="cppturkce" />
<meta property="og:description" content="rand fonksiyonu ile peş peşe zar atıp, inceleme yapıyoruz" />

<!-- Facebook Open Graph Tags end -->
```

Debugger error : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cppturkce.com%2Frand-ile-zar-ornegi%2F

Response Code:  200
Fetched URL:    http://www.cppturkce.com/rand-ile-zar-ornegi/
Canonical URL:  http://www.cppturkce.com/rand-ile-zar-ornegi/

What can i do ?

Comment: The HTML validator says you have invalid closing tags. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cppturkce.com%2Frand-ile-zar-ornegi%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 . Maybe, you need to correct your HTML before you check in debugger.

Comment: These are twitter's tags :/ And they are working perfectly fine

Comment: It's valid now http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cppturkce.com%2Frand-ile-zar-ornegi%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: I probably "think" its because of the special characters in the content. Try providing unicode characters in place of those special ones.

Comment: for example ? this url no special chars : http://www.cppturkce.com/gonullu-editorler-araniyor/ and still error http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cppturkce.com%2Fgonullu-editorler-araniyor%2F

Comment: For example, the og title: <meta property="og:title" content="Gönüllü editörler aranıyor"/>
Look at the special characters in the content.

Comment: That is my language, and it's normal. There are millions of website using this characters with facebook

Comment: True. But it doesnt hurt to try with just English and see if it works. If yes, then provide unicode characters for your language symbols.